# How can I easily move containers with swift

Tags: uikit

I have 4 containers and need to move them up 40 pixels together. Can i move all of them at once.

I have tried changing the rect of them one by one, but when rotation occurs everything is messed up.

Comment: You are going to need to add significantly more detail about the scenario you're trying to set up, what your exact current method of implementation is, and exactly what "when rotation occurs everything is messed up" means, exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very easy actually. In IB create your top, bottom, left and right constraints with heights as well. And then ctrl drag the top constraint with connects the top view to the top of the superview.

Go to your class and just give the desired constant value as you wish.

```
@IBOutlet weak var moveConstant: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

and then

```
 @IBAction func moveTop(sender: AnyObject) {

    moveConstant.constant = 40

}
```